# Special Characters For Python

Tags: python, authentication

I made a login to a python program I created. Is there any way to make the characters show up as stars or something other than the actual character? I am using Python version 3.4.2, I need something I can put in my script. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code are you currently using for the purpose? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Your question could use a few more details. For example: is this a command line program? Is it a GUI app? Is it a web application talking to a Python script? Without knowing those, it'll be hard for someone to give you an answer more specific than the one below by @Doorknob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `getpass` module:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getpass  # the getpass function
<function unix_getpass at 0x7f7dc25f60d0>
>>> getpass.getpass('Enter password: ')  # call it with a prompt
Enter password: 
'this is a password'
```

It will hide the characters being typed.

Comment: Do i add this in the script in IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read passwords either using no-echo from a TTY or just a direct stdin line read, only as a fallback.

Instead call a "password helper" program that is provided via an environment variable such as "TTY_ASKPASS".  ("ssh" and even "sudo" can do this!)

This means not only can a user provide a 'ask password with stars' but they can also input the password from other sources like a keyring daemon, or GUI popup.

Do not limit your users!